# different styles for homepage and rest of the site

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm completely new to Codex and PHP, just started learning it two days ago.
I am converting my html and css over to Wordpress.

I have two style sheets, one for my static front-page and the main stylesheet for the rest of the pages. I'm completely going overboard in my head. I'm trying to figure out how to make a `if` and `else` statement.

So if the front page is loaded, open this style sheet. If not, load the main stylesheet.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
function register_more_stylesheets() {
 wp_enqueue_style( 'style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() );
}
 function add_my_stylesheet() {
    if ( is_front_page() )
  wp_register_style( 'homestyle', get_template_directory_uri() . '/homestyle.css' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_more_stylesheets' );
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_my_stylesheet' );
```

Another thing I'm getting messed up with is my link rel to all this..

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo("template_directory"); ?>/homestyle.css" />
```

This is all in the header.php, I'm linking both, but both seem to be kind of colliding both my stylesheets.

Answer (score 0):

Following basic code convention from **Codex WordPress** or default **Themes**  you can easily handle this problem.

#### Usage

```
wp_enqueue_style( $handle, $src, $deps, $ver, $media );
```

#### Using Hook

```
 /**
  * Proper way to enqueue scripts and styles
  */
  function wpdocs_theme_name_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style-name', get_stylesheet_uri() );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name', get_template_directory_uri() .      '/js/example.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
  }
  add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpdocs_theme_name_scripts' );
```

Answer (score -1):

Use Something like this:

```
<?php if(is_home()) { ?>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php     bloginfo("template_directory"); ?>/homestyle.css" /> 
<?php } else { ?>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>">
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Put below code to your `functions.php` file:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'register_plugin_styles' );

function register_plugin_styles() {
    wp_register_style( 'single-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() );
    wp_register_style( 'home-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/homestyle.css' );

    if( is_single() )
        wp_enqueue_style( 'single-style' );
    else
        wp_enqueue_style( 'home-style' );
}
```